# Java - pattern for textfield

Tags: java, design-patterns, textfield

I want user to type some text in JTextField and it must match some "pattern".

Pattern is - int x, String("hours"), so f.e. **5 hours** ; **12 hours** etc.

I googled something with patterns, matchers, regex or whatever, and I am pretty confused.

If someone ever experienced similar problem, or knows how to handle mine, please post.
Or at least some API to read ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JFormattedTextField](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) should do.